# Mis-understand of copy file in docker images

Tags: docker, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, localhost, containers

Hello could someone pleas help me on copying docker(I'm starter) host file into my jupyter/pyspark-notebook images. I've pulled this notebook from docker as public available.

I've created a Dockerfile which contains this.

```
FROM jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest
ADD /home/abdoulaye/Documents/M2BIGDATA/Jaziri /bin/bash
```

I've changed `/bin/bash` to `.` but nothing is visible.
when I execute `docker built` it's like it copy files as shown in output below.
[image: img] 
when I go to my my notebook I did note found folders. I check my snapshot if I can found these copied folder but I'm very confused.

In clear, I've an running notebook in my docker I use it in y navigator but I can not load data. I like to copy data in place where I can access it in notebook. [image: img2]

Comment: Why /bin/bash? That seems like an odd place to put files. Have you searched for the files? Also try inspecting the container to see if any volumes are present at that location

Comment: I’ve replaced "." By bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not copy using absoult path, the path should be relative to Dockerfile, so `/home/abdoulaye/Documents/M2BIGDATA/Jaziri` this path inside Dockerfile is not correct. Copy file to Dockerfile context and then copy like

```
ADD M2BIGDATA/Jaziri /work
```

Now First thing, you should not copy files from host to executable files directory.

For instance,

```
FROM alpine
copy hello.txt /bin/sh
```

If you copy like this, it will create a problem to run command inside container as `sh` or `bash` will be replaced or corrupt.

2nd, while you are building the docker image with invalid context, it should be the same where your Dockerfile is, so better to run the directory where you place the Dockerfile.

```
docker build -t my-jupyter .
```

3rd, you should not run `cp` command inside container to copy files from host to container.

```
docker cp /home/abdoulaye/Documents/M2BIGDATA/Jaziri container_id:/work
```

it will copy your files to `/work` path of the container.